# Using custom DispatchServlet class instead of xml but unable to remove the xml existence

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I used to have a dispatcher-servlet.xml along side with the web.xml, but when I tried to remove the usage of xml, so I started from removing the dispatcher-servlet.xml and adding the following custom servlet class:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class MyDispatchServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6123340097370999914L;

    public MyDispatchServlet() {
        super();
        System.out.println("is MyDispatchServlet");
    }
}
```

And the web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.infrastructure.MyDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And however when I removed the existing dispatcher-servlet.xml and start the tomcat server, it prints out the line from my MyDispatchServlet.java

```
is MyDispatchServlet
```

However it will also return error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
```

And I don't know where else the xml file is referred by. There is little resource online about using java class instead of bean definition.

Anything I missed?

Comment: You servlet class extends DispatcherServlet, but don't redefine any parent class methods. It inherits all behavior of parent class. So your servlet looking for /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml as well as his parent class, because you didn't change anything in MyDispatchServlet.

Comment: @KenBekov could you add a brief example of what you suggest to change in the MyDispatchServlet (the orverwrite of the correspoding methods) and I will be gladly accept it as answer :) Thanks!